# Use Google text recognition to get text displayed on the screen

Tags: android, android-service, screenshot, ocr, google-vision

My goal is to use an OCR library to get the text displayed on the screen.
Example : you are on the youtube app, normally you can't copy the description. My project is to get this text that I can't copy. I actualy use a Service that overlays a button and when pressed, I would like it puts into the clipboard all the text displayed on the screen.

I've setup Google text recognition and I can give a bitmap to detect text from.
So now I have to get a bitmap of the screen.

But I can't take a screenshot of the whole screen from a Service. From what I saw the only solution is to use MediaProjection. I would like to know if a simpler solution exists. If not, can you give me how would you do, please ?

Thank you.